# SQL Server 'ignores' drop table command

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, drop-table

I have a 500+ lines stored proccedure which I am writting and testing using the Microsoft SQL Management studio. Today I encounter the following 'strange' case. My query (in pseudocode) look like the following

```
create table #TempTable1 (Name varchar(30))

-- Some queries involving #TempTable1

drop table #TempTable1

-- Some queries

declare MyCursor cursor fast_forward for 
select ......

open MyCursor

fetch next from MyCursor into @CursorValue
while @@fetch_status = 0
   begin

       create table #TempTable1 (Name varchar(30))

       -- Some queries involving #TempTable1

       drop table #TempTable1 

       fetch next from MyCursor into @CursorValue

    end

close MyCursor 
deallocate MyCursor
```

My query fails with an error in the second `create table`

> There is already an object named '#TempTable1' in the database.

I know that due to query optimizations the commands are not running in the sequence I am typing them. However this error still seems strange to me. I can put some `go` commands to force the execution, but this will create some other problems in my code e.g. I will have to redeclare some variables e.t.c. Renaming the tables will solve the problem but it will harm a little the readabillity of the code. So it is more 'curiocity' than an 'actual problem'.

Any suggestions on why this is happening and how I can avoid it?

Comment: Do you require the first temptable `#TempTable1` inside the cursor

Comment: No I do not need it, that's why I am dropping it before it.

Comment: As I said, I can solve the problem by renaming the table, but out of curiocity I want to know why this is happening. Moreover the `#TempTable1` is not the real name of my table, I am using something more descriptive based on its contents.

Comment: I have updated my answer please see. You are not allowed to create temptable with same in single query or batch

Comment: Be aware of [temp table caching](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/17/temporary-object-caching-explained.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see you are creating temptable with same name.You cannot create temp table with same name in single query or batch this is documented as per BOL document. From [Bol document](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.100).aspx)

> If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored procedure or batch, they must have different names.

You should use below logic it will just check before creating and deleting

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temptable1') IS NOT NULL

   DROP TABLE #Temptable1

CREATE TABLE #Temptable1(name nvarchar(30))
```

Which would make your query like

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temptable1') IS NOT NULL

       DROP TABLE #Temptable1

    CREATE TABLE #Temptable1(name nvarchar(30))

-- Some queries involving #TempTable1

   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temptable1') IS NOT NULL

       DROP TABLE #Temptable1



-- Some queries

declare MyCursor cursor fast_forward for 
select ......

open MyCursor

fetch next from MyCursor into @CursorValue
while @@fetch_status = 0
   begin

          IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temptable2') IS NOT NULL--new temp table

       DROP TABLE #Temptable2

    CREATE TABLE #Temptable1(name nvarchar(30))

       -- Some queries involving #TempTable1

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temptable2') IS NOT NULL

       DROP TABLE #Temptable2

       fetch next from MyCursor into @CursorValue

    end

close MyCursor 
deallocate MyCursor
```

Comment: I was searching for the very same resource! I was not aware that SQL Server behaves that way on create table.

Comment: Just a side note to your anwser, checking if a table exists or not, is not a solution to my problem. The only solution is to rename one of the Tempopary Tables, or to truncate it instead of droping it.

Comment: Yes you are correct that is why I mentioned it at top in my answer but if you are creating and dropping multiple temp  tables in your query  I have always seen checking avoids any unforeseen error.